Debian 12 - Can I get a better error message when I forget to type sudo?
Former Ubuntu user transitioning to Debian
When I type a command that requires sudo in Debian but forget to prepend the sudo I get a super unhelpful, even incorrect error message command not found
For example
Forgot to type sudo
$ dmidecode
bash: dmidecode: command not found

Typed sudo
$ sudo dmidecode 
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
68 structures occupying 2743 bytes.
Table at 0x000EB9E0.

In Ubuntu I got a more helpful error message along the lines of "you must be root to use this command" or something similar.
Is there a way to get a better error message in Debian?

In response to comments
Giving the full path of the command does give a more helpful error message:
$ /usr/sbin/dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.4
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
/dev/mem: Permission denied

So this likely is a path problem.

Presumably dmidecode is in your sudoers secure_path but not in your user's PATH? Perhaps Debian does not install the command-not-found package by default (or your shell is not loading the default command_not_found_handle() ?

If you can enumerate the commands that require sudo that you use, you can alias them to an echo (or printf) of an appropriate message.

what happens if you type the full path to dmidecode?

Debian does not, indeed, install command-not-found by default @steeldriver

@jsotola great suggestion! Edited with the results.

add /usr/sbin to your path

@jsotola that worked! If you care to post an answer I'll accept it with thanks.

The command resides at /usr/sbin/dmidecode.
Your user account is not configured to check /usr/sbin directory for the existence of dmidecode.
Add /usr/sbin to your path variable.
Run the following command
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH

To make the change permanent, add the command to your .bashrc file (if you are using bash)

As noted by steeldriver in the comments, you need to have command-not-found installed:
sudo apt install command-not-found
sudo apt update # To update command-not-found's database

And be running a shell which is configured to use it, such as bash. You will need to start a new shell, after which you should see something like this:
muru@ded66325485b:~$ dmidecode
Command 'dmidecode' is available in the following places
 * /sbin/dmidecode
 * /usr/sbin/dmidecode
The command could not be located because '/sbin:/usr/sbin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
This is most likely caused by the lack of administrative privileges associated with your user account.
dmidecode: command not found

This is from a container running debian:12.

Thanks for the answer, and it will help some, I'm sure. For me adding command-not-found has other implications; I would have to mirror the files it needs in my local mirror, and I don't want to do that just for this (I had to hack my Ubuntu mirror scripts to get it to work in apt-mirror). Just updating my path works well enough.

I found with openSUSE Leap 15.5 that /usr/sbin wasn't on the PATH for a non-root user (when tested a live image).
From /usr/sbin is not in $PATH on Debian 11 bullseye. Is this correct? this is also true for Debian.
I.e. adding /usr/sbin to your PATH for the user account is one work-around.
